# LibGDX Deployment questions

Tags: libgdx, ios, macos

A few questions from LibGDX newbie:

- How do you deploy a Mac/Windows app? If Mac app, can this be deployed to Mac App Store?
- Do you need to pay monthly (for RoboVM) for iOS development/deployment?

I am using Android Studio. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Answering (just) point number 2.
RoboVM is free, but if you want the Debugging capabilities you need to shell out some money.  Fortunately, right now for indie developers this fee can be null since there's some sort of agreement between libGDX and RoboVM.

You need to get your free RoboVM license, and then apply for the indie "upgrade".

No small letters, is even says: "The license will be automatically renewed every year. You can use it for as many games as you want, no strings attached."

More info here: http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=37621[1](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3762)

Answer (score 0):

With libGDX, you can either create a runnable JAR file or a native application file.  To get your app on the Mac App Store, you will need to go with the second option.  This can most easily be done with a tool called [packr](https://github.com/libgdx/packr).  What it does is it packages your JAR file (all the code and assets) with a JRE (Java Runtime Environment) into a standalone .app file that can be run on Mac.  For more information on how to create a Windows/Mac app [this wiki page](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Deploying-your-application#deploy-to-ios) should help you.

To deploy apps to the Mac and iOS App Stores, as well as test your apps on physical iOS devices, you will need to pay the yearly Apple Developer fee of 99 USD.  This should work with libGDX apps.

RoboVM seems to be free for commercial use with libGDX, so the yearly 99 USD Apple License is the only required fee.

Comment: [It is bad form on stackexchange to only link to information instead of providing it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Your answer could be improved by explaining how to create an application instead of just linking to a wiki article which might no longer exist in a few years.

Comment: @Philipp I have edited my answer to provide more (hopefully useful) information.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but are you sure RoboVM is free? I wanted to export to iOS but when wanted to download RoboVM, found that it is quite expensive: http://robovm.com/pricing/

Comment: For Mac, how do you create he runnable JAR in the first place?

Comment: @LimThyeChean Creating a runnable JAR depends entirely upon the IDE you're working in but it should be in the project's export options.  In Eclipse it should be Project->Export->Java->Runnable JAR.  As for the RoboVM pricing, the core features are available for free but the subscription plans give you additional features and services.

Comment: @LimThyeChean If you scroll down on the link you provided to the pricing page, there is a "Free" download option :)

Comment: @Alex I am using Android Studio, I find no export or instructions on how to export Java Runnable... as for RoboVM, do you have any resources that can guide me from a simple libGDX to an iOS app? I tried running the iOS build from Android Studio and it crashes (I assume this is because I need to install RoboVM first).

Comment: @LimThyeChean You would have to make gradle build a jar for you then I assume...  https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-on-the-Commandline#packaging-for-the-desktop This link should help with that.  If you scroll down to the 'packaging for ios' section, that will hopefully help with your second issue.

Comment: @Alex I can create the runnable JAR and works fine in OS X and Windows! Still cannot get the Packr to work (using the command prompt). It will be more than just create an OS X package or EXE to upload to Mac App Store or Windows Store, isn't it? You will need to sandbox, etc.